# my grid does not seem to be laying out the content as a grid

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let tea_grid = document.querySelector(".tea_grid");
for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
fetch("https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos/?query=tea-leaves&client_id=QSz12piqsEZKwy7mseJIbTRYnc6SD1WgF91DNS7wp70")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); 
    let images = data.results[randomNumber];
    console.log(images.urls.regular)
    let randomImage = images.urls.full;

    let tea = document.createElement("div");
    tea.classList.add("tea")

    let image = document.createElement("div");
    image.classList.add("image")
    image.style.backgroundImage = `url(${randomImage})`;
    tea.append(image)

    tea_grid.append(tea)

    });
};
```

```css
.tea-grid {

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    gap: 30px;
    width: fit-content;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.tea {

    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #f5f5f1;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.image {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 60%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;

}
```

```html
  <body>
      <div class="tea_grid">

      </div>
  </body>
```

I am trying to randomly get images from an API and then display them on the HTML page in a responsive grid. But the grid keeps just going down in a line. I have tried changing the grid in the CSS but it does not work. I'm not 100% sure what it could be. But my only thought is that the javascript is affecting it somehow.

Comment: i think just typo `tea-grid` -> `tea_grid`

Comment: @dangerousmanleesanghyeon oh my god I'm so sorry for the dumb question I can't believe  I didn't see that. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

was a type in the CSS and HTML as @dangerousmanleesanghyeon pointed out.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).